# Multiple Iframe trigger play()

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've multiple `iframe` Vimeo videos on the same page. Each video has an image cover with a play icon to hide the default player. When the user click the cover, the cover fade out and play the video.

My code works only if there is one `iframe` per page. It fails if there is two or more `iframe` per page.

The HTML for the `iframe`:

```
<div class="o-iframe">
    <div class="o-iframe__wrapper">
        <div class="o-iframe__cover js-iframe-cover">
            <div class="o-iframe__cover-icon"></div>
        </div>
        <iframe class="o-iframe__element js-iframe" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
if (document.querySelector('.js-iframe')) {

    var video = new Vimeo.Player(document.querySelector('.js-iframe'));
    var videoCover = document.querySelector('.js-iframe-cover');

    videoCover.addEventListener('click', function() {
        videoCover.style.opacity = '0';
        video.play();
    });

    videoCover.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
        this.remove();
    });
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelectorAll and ***forEach*** is the key here. Target every `class="o-iframe"` elements on the page. Inside the each function target the descendants using `elOIframe.querySelector()`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.o-iframe').forEach(elOIframe => {

  const elCover = elOIframe.querySelector('.js-iframe-cover');
  const elIframe = elOIframe.querySelector(".js-iframe");
  const video = new Vimeo.Player(elIframe);

  elCover.addEventListener('click', function() {
    elCover.style.opacity = '0';
    video.play();
  });

  elCover.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    elCover.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="o-iframe">
  <div class="o-iframe__wrapper">
    <div class="o-iframe__cover js-iframe-cover">
      <div class="o-iframe__cover-icon"></div>
    </div>
    <iframe class="o-iframe__element js-iframe" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- and many other <div class="o-iframe"> here -->
```

Comment: Nice @MathieuPréaud glad to hear